# Why does numpy's broadcasting sometimes allow comparing arrays of different lengths?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to understand how numpy's broadcasting affects the output of `np.allclose`.

```
>>> np.allclose([], [1.])
True
```

I don't see why that works, but this does not:

```
>>> np.allclose([], [1., 2.])
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (2,)
```

What are the rules here? I can't finding anything in the [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) regarding empty arrays.

Comment: `Two dimensions are compatible when they are equal, or one of them is 1` - well this certainly is true, so by definition the two should be broadcasting compatible. However I do not see how this intuitively makes sense for a dimension 0 vs 1.

Comment: @cel: see answer below

Comment: @cel consider `np.allclose([], 1)`. Their dimension are `(0,)` and `()`, so neither equal nor 1. Is that the only compatibility rule?

Comment: @WilfredHughes, `(0,)` and `()` are the shapes, not the dimensions. The dimensions are `1` and `0` I would say (not 100% sure, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcasting rules apply to addition as well,

```
In [7]: np.array([])+np.array([1.])
Out[7]: array([], dtype=float64)

In [8]: np.array([])+np.array([1.,2.])
....

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (2,)
```

Let's look at the shapes.

```
In [9]: np.array([]).shape,np.array([1.]).shape,np.array([1,2]).shape
Out[9]: ((0,), (1,), (2,))
```

(0,) and (1,) - the `(1,)` can be adjusted to match the shape of the other array.  A `1` dimension can be adjusted to match the other array, from example increased from 1 to 3.  But here it was (apparently) adjusted from 1 to 0.  I don't usually work with arrays with a 0 dimension, but this looks like a proper generalization of higher dimensions.

Try (0,) and (1,1).  The result is (1,0):

```
In [10]: np.array([])+np.array([[1.]])
Out[10]: array([], shape=(1, 0), dtype=float64)
```

(0,), (1,1) => (1,0),(1,1) => (1,0)

As for the 2nd case with shapes (0,) and (2,); there isn't any size 1 dimension to adjust, hence the error.

Shapes (0,) and (2,1) do broadcast (to (2,0)):

```
In [12]: np.array([])+np.array([[1.,2]]).T
Out[12]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=float64)
```

Answer (score 1):

Broadcasting doesn't affect `np.allclose` in any other way than it affects any other function.

As in the comment by @cel, `[1.]` is of dimension 1 and so can be broadcasted to any other dimension, including 0. On the other hand `[1., 2.]` is of dimension 2 and thus cannot be broadcasted.

Now why `allclose([],[1.]) == True`? This actually makes sense: it means that all elements in `[]` are close to `1.`. The opposite would mean that there is at least one element in `[]` which is not close to `1.` which is obviously `False` since there are no elements at all in `[]`.

Another way to think about it is to ask yourself how you would actually code `allclose()`:

```
def allclose(array, target=1.):
    for x in array:
        if not isclose(x, target):
            return False
    return True
```

This would return `True` when called with `[]`.

Comment: I agree in principle, but how would you interpret `np.allclose([1.],[])` which is also `True`? All elements in [1.] are equal to .. hum...nothing? The other way feels very unintuitive.

Comment: @cel: because you should not read it this way: `[1.]` is broadcasted to `[]` not the other way around. (The same way it is `[1.]` that would be broadcasted to `[1., 2., 3.]` and not the other way around which would also be nonsense.)